# How to refractor a long function (efficient coding)

Tags: php, function

Maybe I'm asking something that I can find on Google. But is there someone who is willing to help me to make my code more efficient? Apart from this specific question, all tips for efficient coding are welcome!

This is my code:

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
        if (date("m-d", strtotime($d['gebdatum'])) == $today) {
            $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>is vandaag '.$d['leeftijd'].' geworden</td></tr>';
        }

        if (date("m-d", strtotime($d['gebdatum'])) == $today+1) {
            $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>wordt morgen '.$d['leeftijd'].' jaar</td></tr>';
        }

        if (date("m-d", strtotime($d['gebdatum'])) == $today+2) {
            $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>wordt overmorgen '.$d['leeftijd'].' jaar</td></tr>';
        }

        if (date("m-d", strtotime($d['odienst'])) == $today) {
            $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>werkt vandaag '.$d['jubileum'].' jaar bij Kuijpers</td></tr>';
        }

        if (date("m-d", strtotime($d['odienst'])) == $today+1) {
            $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>werkt morgen '.$d['jubileum'].' jaar bij Kuijpers</td></tr>';
        }

        if (date("m-d", strtotime($d['odienst'])) == $today+2) {
            $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>werkt overmorgen '.$d['jubileum'].' jaar bij Kuijpers</td></tr>';
        }
    }
```

I'm sure this code can be brought back to a single set of lines. But how?

Comment: To save your html tags with the data in a string isn't the best idea, since it will be hard to find and change something. I would re-think your code and just save the data in an array. And then if you want to display it then print the data between the tags

Comment: This looks like Afrikaans, something about week days? Maybe if you translated it into English people would be better able to help. Also, are you unable to do this yourself? Refactoring something like this is just a matter of fiddling with the code until it is as simple as you can get it.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It's Dutch. It's about birthdays. vandaag=today, morgen=tomorrow, overmorgen= the day after tomorrow

Comment: My answer should work. I just tested it.

Comment: Please tell me if it worked. If not, tell me the problem with it.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on the [Code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a for loop. Though you have to declare vandaag, morgen and overmorgen before that. Like so:

```
$today=date('m-d');
$array=array(0=>'is vandaag',1=>'wordt morgen',2=>'wordt overmorgen');
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
      $pos=strpos($array[$i], ' ');
   $geboortedatum=date("m-d", strtotime($d['gebdatum']));
   $jubileum=date("m-d", strtotime($d['odienst']));
   if (date($geboortedatum, strtotime('+'.$i.' days')) == date('m-d')) {
        $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>'.$array[$today+$i].' '.$d['leeftijd'].' jaar</td></tr>';
    }
    if (date($jubileum, strtotime('+'.$i.' days')) == date('m-d')) {
        $alltable .= '<tr><td>'.$d['voornaam'].' '.$d['naam'].'&emsp;</td><td>werkt '.substr($array[$today+$i], $pos).' '.$d['jubileum'].' jaar bij Kuijpers</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

At the odienst I made sure the `is` and `wordt` are gone for the grammar.

Comment: It's not working. I think the problem is the $today+$i, i have declared $today = date("m-d"); so that will be 04-15 for today. But $today+1 gives "5", so that's not the date of tomorrow.